# How to implement two panel layout using Angular Ui-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my code

```js
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider
        .state('student',{
          url: '/student',
          
          views: {
            'list': {
              templateUrl: 'list.html',
              controller: 'StudentsCtrl'
            },
            'edit':{
              templateUrl: 'edit.html',
              controller: 'StudentEditCtrl'
            }
          }
        })

    }]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<div ui-view="list"></div>
<div ui-view="edit"></div>
</html>
```

I have layout with two panels side by side,i tried the above code but at the time of page loading two panels html pages displayed at a time. But i want to display first list.html in left side then user clicks add or edit buttons in list.html that time render the edit.html in right side of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't combine the HTML and controller together?  The StudentCtrl could toggle showing the edit html when the add or edit buttons are clicked.

I can't think of a simple way to make it work with how you have it designed now.  You'd have to some coordinating controller in your main HTML and/or some sort of shared Angular service which seems messy.